# Copying Data between two similar Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb6

I have two databases, Database A and Database B, which are the same except for about few new columns in some tables in Database B.

The two databases contain the same number of tables (1160 tables). I  added columns to about 40 tables in Database B. That is the only thing different from Database A.

I have emptied all tables in Database B and want to insert all data in each tables of Database A to Database B, leaving only the 40 tables that have the number of columns different from the source Database A.

I need a script to loop through all tables in Database A, check if the columns are the same, then copy its contents to that table in Database B. If the columns are not the same, it should leave an error of the table name.

Comment: So what is your question and what have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried a : "Select * into DatabaseB.dbo.table1 From DatabaseA.dbo.table1....That works, but i need a script that can loop through all tables and copy the contents of each table of Database A into each corresponding tables in Database B

Comment: @DoreenSly, Are you still waiting for answer? are all your tables in DBO schema? do you have identity fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming all your tables are DBO. 
in case you have identity field, see my comment

```
-- select only tables that have the same number of columns
declare tbls cursor for with tblsA as (
select t.name, count(*) as colCount
from DatabaseA.sys.tables t
    inner join DatabaseA.sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
group by t.name
)
, tblsB as (
select t.name, count(*) as colCount
from DatabaseB.sys.tables t
    inner join DatabaseB.sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
group by t.name
)
select tblsA.name as TableName
from tblsA 
   inner join tblsB on tblsB.name = tblsA.name and tblsB.colCount = tblsA.colCount


declare @tblName varchar(100)
declare @sqlText nvarchar(max)
open tbls
fetch next from tbls into @tblName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    print 'Inserting into ' + @tblName 

    --un-comment if you don't have identity fields. 
    --you will need more code here if some table have identity field and some don't
    --set @sqlText = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT DatabaseB..' + @tblName + ' ON'
    --exec(@sqlText)

    set @sqlText = 'insert into DatabaseB..' + @tblName + ' select * from DatabaseA..' + @tblName
    exec(@sqlText)

    fetch next from tbls into @tblName
end

close tbls
deallocate tbls
```

Comment: @Flicker......Thanks a Zillion times...worked perfectly as i have wanted. It moved datas of the tables with same column and skipped the unequal ones.....I used the same code to get the list of the few unuequal tables and i am moving their own data one after the other.